# Patterns in binary sequences

Tags: time-series, pattern-recognition, similarities

I have data that looks like this:

```
011100111110100111
111111111111110010
111100001111000011
```

1D lanes of streams of data. Each row signifies the presence of a thing at that time with a 1 or a 0. Things tend to exist in consecutive chunks across the stream. The vertical order of the rows doesn't matter, patterns can occur between any set of rows.

I am seeking patterns where dimensions coincide at two or more indices, both at the **start of '1' group's**, and also **where any '1' groups overlap** across all rows/dimensions.

Pattern can be offset with nearby adjacent indices, if it's proportion is maintained.

D = Dimension/Row
N = Index in stream

```
(( D1(N), D25(N+4), D900(N-1) ), ( 3, 67, 90, 3000 ))

D1(3),    D25(7),    D900(2)
D1(67),   D25(71),   D900(66)
D1(90),   D25(94),   D900(89)
D1(3000), D25(3004), D900(2999)
```

An example of a pattern match that migh occur at multiple places.  Dimension01 at N, Dimension25 at index N + 4, Dimension900 at index N -1 occur at indices 3, 67, 90 and 3000.

#### The returned patterns:

- Are ordered by the number of matching indices or by the number of dimensions in the pattern.
- Match at least two dimensions at at least two points

How can I go about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binary time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197084/binary-time-series)